# Alternative for deprecated WifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks and WifiManager.removeNetwork methods on Android Q?

Tags: android, adb, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

For a UiTest class setup, I need to begin with no remembered Wifi Networks.
To do this I use a combination of the *WifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()* and *WifiManager.removeNetwork()*, both of which are now restricted and deprecated for Android Q.

Now, since I am running the tests in privileged mode (super user), the *getConfiguredNetworks()* method actually returns a full list of the networks, and the *removeNetwork()* removes networks I pass by returned WifiConfiguration's Ids, even though I run this code on an Android Q device.

**TLDR:**
My issue is more about these two methods being deprecated without being properly replaced, not that they now are worthless to use. At least not to my knowing, which is why I am asking; are there any way I, with my testapplication run as Super-user, can:

1. Retrieve all Wifi Configurations
2. Delete them one by one

In [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager), one can read:

> **getConfiguredNetworks()**
>
> This method was deprecated in API level 29. a) See WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder#build() for new mechanism to trigger connection to a Wi-Fi network. b) See addNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List), removeNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List) for new API to add Wi-Fi networks for consideration when auto-connecting to wifi. Compatibility Note: For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will return an empty list.

The solutions they've linked seem to be for the action of connecting to wifi networks, but that isn't what I am looking for.

PS, I would be at least as happy by executing adb shell commands (in superuser-mode if needed), to do the same thing. Already tried using **wpa_cli list_networks** to at least list all networks, but doesn't seem to be available.

Also have tried to remove **data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant** and **data/misc_ce/0/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml**, to no avail.

Comment: Hi @MahNas92. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro, unfortunately I haven't found any viable alternative to date, and am still running the deprecated method(s).